# how to bind models during OPA testing?

Tags: testing, sapui5

I have a simple OPA5 test for my SAPUI5 app to check that a table is displayed when I click a button. When the test runs it clicks on the button and the table shows up but the there is no data on it. Using console logs on my code I can see that the data is being set properly. Here are my code snippets. Is there a way to wait for the data to be bound before proceeding to check for the table?

Code to be tested:

```
        var errorsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);
        oComponent.setModel(errorsModel, "errors_inputs");
        console.log(oComponent.getModel("errors_inputs"));
```

OPA Test:

```
opaTest("Should press the Process button and see the  formatting errors table", function (Given, When, Then) {
    // Actions  
    When.onCheckingErrortables.iPressTheProcessButtonWithBadData();

    // Assertions
    Then.onCheckingErrortables.iShouldSeeTheErrorsTableWithOneRow();
});
```

PageObjects for this test:

```
actions: {

            iPressTheProcessButtonWithBadData: function(){
                return this.waitFor({
                    viewName: inputsView,
                    id: "processBtn",
                    actions: new Press(),
                    errorMessage: "No Process button found"
                });
            }
        },

        assertions: {
            iShouldSeeTheErrorsTableWithOneRow: function () {
                return this.waitFor({
                    viewName: inputsView,
                    id: "errors_table",
                    matchers: new AggregationFilled({name: "rows"}),
                    success: function (rows) {
                        Opa5.assert.ok(rows.getRows().length === 1, "The Errors Table is visible and contains one row");
                    },
                    errorMessage: "Errors Tables does not have the right number of rows"
                });
```

Comment: where in the process are you setting the JSONmodel?

Comment: I have it defined in my manifest.json file. 
"models": {
            "errors_inputs": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
            }
}

Comment: No I mean , setting the data. Not defining the component. I’m just wondering what happens first... if you’re setting data in component but you’re testing main controller init function, controller will finish first etc.

Comment: It's on the first code snippet:
var errorsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);
        oComponent.setModel(errorsModel, "errors_inputs");

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I know a) the definition of the model is on the manifest and b) how you're loading data into it. I do *not* know c) where in your code that snippet is located. Component initialisation? Controller initialisation? Route matched? Any other spot?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. in my OPA html file I had to add the line 'data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" ' It seemed to be something with how the binding itself was being done and OPA5 didn't understand what I was doing

Comment: You bind your model in mockserver.js if you are using mockdata since OPA is supposed to work with MOCKDATA for onepage acceptance testing. You basically create the mockdata using the metatada and use the data for mocking the application and test the OPA. For more information please visit this link -  [MOCKSERVER](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/69d3cbd4150c4ffb884e788f7f60fd93)

Answer (score 0):

> Checking for the aggregation "items" worked for me.

Here's what I did:

```js
return this.waitFor({
  viewName: inputsView,
  id: "errors_table",
  matchers: new AggregationFilled({
    name: "items"
  }),
  success: function(oTable) {
    Opa5.assert.ok(oTable, "The Errors Table is visible ");
  },
  errorMessage: "Errors Tables does not have the right number of rows"
});
```